# Blender True displacement option not available

Tags: interface, displacement

I tried to turn on true displacement, so I turned on experimental features but when I go to the object settings, where the displacement options are, there isn't anything there:

[image: No Displacement]

As you can see, I have experimental features turned on:

[image: i just cant]

I don't know what to do, how do I turn true displacement on?

Comment: You find the displacement settings in the materials panel

Comment: Did you try to render?

Comment: The displacement setting in the material panel are there, yes, but when I render it's just as if it had a normal map despite being subdivided, so no true displacement. Edit: Looks like it was in the materials settings, so never mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You find the displacement settings in the materials panel. There you can set it to "true displacement".
[image]

Comment: Oh, thank you. Was this changed recently? In any guides I found, it said the displacement options were in the object settings.

Comment: When the feature first came out, Blender Guru made a tutorial about it (link coming soon) and I can't remember that the option was at a different place than it is now. I'll look that up later.

Comment: https://youtu.be/dRzzaRvVDng?t=18m14s